# Rails Trying to create a profile after the user has been created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, devise

I'm trying to figure out how to create a new profile for the user that has just been created,

I'm using devise on the User model, and the User model has a one to one relationship with the UserProfile model.

Here's what my User Model looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  belongs_to :batch
  has_one :user_profile

  after_create :create_user_profile

  def create_user_profile
    self.user_profile.new(:name => 'username')
  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

This generate the following error:

> undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

i've tried **User.find(1).user_profile** in **rails c** and that works so I'm pritty sure the relationship is setup correctly,

I'm probably being a big fat noob and trying to fetch **self** incorrectly.

plus can you also tell me how to access the params in a Model... is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A has_one relationship will automatically add the `:create_<relationship>` and `build_<relationship>` methods. [Checkout the rails guide.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one)

You could try this:

```
after_create do
  create_user_profile(:name => 'username')
end
```

Or more likely

```
after_create do
  create_user_profile(:name => self.username)
end
```

Comment: Thanks john... that worked for me... do you have any idea how i can use params to add the name instead of entering a static value? I want to add a username field to the user's new form... is that possible?